# Оптимизировать запись в бд. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть база SQLite, с таблицами - `Messages` и `Users`. Содержит примерно 100 000 пользователей.

Нужно добавлять / обновлять сообщения, и пользователей, которые сделали репосты. На каждые 100 сообщений приходится ~6000 репостнувших пользователей. Сейчас на добавление 1 сообщения (в котором ~300 репостов), если всех репостнувших пользователей еще нет в базе, уходит ~14 секунд (это нормально?).

Делаю так:

```
using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
{
    // Получаем всех пользователей, чтобы сравнивать с репостнувшими пользователями
    usersFromDb = db.Users.ToList();

    /*****
     Т.к. пользователей в базе много, получение всех пользователей не оптимально.
     Но лучше ли будет делать много запросов (для каждого пользователя), вместо этого одного?
    *****/
}

using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
{
    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        if (message.RepostUsers != null)
        {
            // Проходим по списку репостнувших пользователей

            /*****
             Эта часть занимает много времени
             Можно ли оптимизировать?
            *****/
            foreach (var user in message.RepostUsers)
            {
                // Ищем по пользователям из базы
                var dbUser = usersFromDb.Find(u => u.Id == user.Id);
                if (dbUser == null)
                {
                    // Если не нашли, помечаем новым
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else if (dbUser.Name != user.Name)
                {
                    // Если нашли и есть изменения, помечаем измененным
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Если нашли и изменений нет, помечаем не измененным
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }
        }

        // Получаем Message из базы
        var dbMessage = db.Messages.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == message.Id);

        // Message всегда либо новое, либо измененное. Помечаем
        db.Entry(message).State = dbMessage != null ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    }

    db.Messages.AddRange(messages);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Вопрос 1.**
Т.к. пользователей в базе много, получение всех пользователей не оптимально. Но лучше ли будет делать много запросов (отдельно для каждого репостнувшего пользователя), вместо одного?

**Вопрос 2.**
Когда меняю у пользователей состояния через `db.Entry(user).State`, объекты помещаются в кэш для отслеживания изменений? Т.е. `AsNoTracking` не учитывается? Если так, нужно ли это изменить и как?

Comment: Попробуйте `usersFromDb` сделать типа HashSet. Будет в разы быстрее.

Comment: Т.е. `HashSet<User> usersFromDb;`? Тогда не получается `usersFromDb = db.Users.ToList();`

Comment: `usersFromDb = new HashSet(db.Users.ToList())`

Comment: А не стоп. Вам нужен словарь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Итак, что получилось сделать:**

- Вместо получения всех пользователей (1-2 сек.) выполняется выборка только определенных (~0.01 сек.)
- Скорость записи / обновления 100 сообщений (примерно 5000-7000 репостнувших пользователей) составляет 5-7 секунд.

**Проблем было несколько:**

1. Метод `AddRange` не срабатывал, если в базе уже находились добавляемые записи, т.к. `AddRange` устанавливает записям состояние `Added`
2. Для проверки пользователей (нужно ли добавлять или изменять) каждый раз подтягивались все записи из базы, с которыми происходило сравнение. Менее затратно получать пользователей по критериям, используя `where`. Но тут не так все однозначно - если добавлять по 10 сообщений, быстрее делать выборку. Если по 100 сообщений, пользователей много и выборка делается дольше, чем получение всех записей через `ToList()`.
3. Много времени тратилось на изменение статуса записей `db.Entry(user).State =`, т.к. это приводило к дорогостоящему в плане выполнения вызову внутреннего алгоритма [DetectChanges](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/)

**Исправления:**

1. Убираем `AddRange`
2. Делаем выборку пользователей из базы, вместо получения всех
3. Отключаем механизм `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

**Результат:**

```
using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
{
    // Получаем всех пользователей, чтобы сравнивать с репостнувшими пользователями
    usersFromDb = db.Users.Where(x => allUsers.Keys.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
}

using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        if (message.RepostUsers != null)
        {
            // Проходим по списку репостнувших пользователей
            foreach (var user in message.RepostUsers)
            {
                User dbUser = null;

                // Ищем по пользователям из базы
                if (usersFromDb.ContainsKey(user.Id))
                    dbUser = usersFromDb[user.Id];

                if (dbUser == null)
                {
                    // Если не нашли, помечаем новым
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else if (dbUser.Name != user.Name)
                {
                    // Если нашли и есть изменения, помечаем измененным
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Если нашли и изменений нет, помечаем не измененным
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }
        }

        // Получаем Message из базы
        var dbMessage = db.Messages.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == message.Id);

        // Message всегда либо новое, либо измененное. Помечаем
        db.Entry(message).State = dbMessage != null ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    }

    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

*Отдельное спасибо [@Ruslan Artamonov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195080) за подсказки и ответы.*

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю только на вопрос по оптимизации. Вы каждый раз перебираете usersFromDb в поисках Id. Для таких целей надо использовать словарь. Вот код:

```
Dictionary<int,User> usersFromDb;
...
usersFromDb = db.Users.ToDictionary(x=>x.Id, x=>x);
...
// Ищем по пользователям из базы
if (usersFromDb.ContainsKey(userId))
{
    var dbUser = usersFromDb[userId];
...
```

Словарь позволяет совершать поиск за постоянное время O(1). В то время как поиск по листу происходит за линейное время O(n).

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Однако основная медлительность состоит именно при работе с базой - вставка 300 записей за 14 секунд, вроде слишком медленно.

Comment: @Skrim У вас есть возможность посмотреть сколько выполняется метод `db.SaveChanges();`? В современной студии можно смотреть время при отладке.

Comment: Сам `SaveChanges` выполняется не долго. Дольше занимает изменение состояний `db.Entry(user).State`. Выполнил вставку 1 сообщения с 881 репостом, из которых 848 новых пользователей. Результаты (в миллисекундах): весь `foreach` - 16824, `db.SaveChanges();` - 583

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov выкачивать 100 000 юзеров каждый раз?

Comment: @Skrim Сколько будет выполняться такой запрос: `var r = new HashSet(message.RepostUsers); db.Users.Where(x=>r.Contains(x)).ToList();`

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, сделал выборку пользователей по критериям. Если `message.RepostUsers` содержит большое количество, выходит медленнее, чем получать всех пользователей. Иначе обратное. В моем случае использование `Where` подходит, получение пользователей на каждые 10 сообщений (~300-500 пользователей) ускорилось примерно на 1-2 секунды.

Comment: @Skrim попробуйте теперь отказаться от Entry. Сделайте `var dbUsers = new HashSet(db.Users.Where(x=>r.Contains(x))); db.Users.AddRange(r.Except(dbUsers));`.  Еще надо придумать как обновить имя без `db.Entry`

Comment: Да, сам `AddRange` не срабатывал, если в базе уже находились записи, которые нужно было изменить, отказался от него. Переделал так: подтягиваю из базы сообщения, в цикле проверяю и меняю статус у `messages` либо на `EntityState.Modified` либо на `EntityState.Added`, после чего просто вызываю `SaveChanges`. Тормоза были в кэшировании. Сделал перед циклом `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`, после цикла вернул. Скорость записи теперь составляет ~5-7 секунд на 100 сообщений, в которых суммарно содержатся 5-7к пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотри вариант с PostgreSQL, потому что SQLite - реляционная БД. Не вдаюсь в подробности. С одной стороны просто, но чем больше записей в БД, тем тяжелее запросы. Увеличь число записей в два раза в своей БД и посмотришь, стоит ли работать дальше с ней.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но думаю все же SQLite больше подойдет, т.к. всего будет примерно 200 000 записей и дальше расти не будет, только частичное обновление существующих.

Comment: Так PostgreSQL тоже реляционная БД.

Comment: это СУБД, а Lite под это определение не попадает. Когда с БД начинает работать несколько юзеров, вот тогда все недостатки и вылазят.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Понял. Используйте (собака)имя, а то не увидел, что вы мне ответили.