# Entity framework 6. Запись n данных в бд

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Только начал постигать дзэн (Entity). Нужно было записать в простенькую бд из одной таблички порядка 20000 данных. написал не хитрую реализацию, но проблемка в том что на заполнение уходит около 3(!!!) минут. Так вот назрел вопрос, это вообще законно?) Или может (скорее всего так и есть)) проблема во мне?

```
         while (i != 20000)
        {
            mydb.Tables.Add(new Table {...});
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать AddRange вместо Add. Задавал похожий вопрос (смотрите самый нижний ответ) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608416/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Зависит от того, как часто ты вызываешь SaveChanges()

Если ты вызываешь сохранение для каждой записи, то производительность очень низкая.

См. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

2) Может быть сетевая проблема, если СУБД находится на другой машине.

3)Сам по себе EF тормозная штука для операций над большим кол-вом данных.

Например, ручная вставка через какой-нибудь BulkCopy будет быстрее.